# How to properly pass 2D array to Conv1D?

Tags: python, arrays, keras

I have a 2-dimensional array that contains `N` rows of 96-dimensional vectors:

```
[[n_(1 1), n_(1 2), ... , n_(1 96)]
[n_(2, 1), n_(2, 2), ... , n_(2 96)
...
[n_(N, 1), n_(N, 2), ... , n_(N 96)]]
```

I want to pass **each** row vector of the array above to Conv1D classifier defined below:

```
from keras.initializers import Constant, RandomNormal
from keras.layers import Conv1D
from keras.activations import softmax

classifier_conv = Conv1D(filters=4,
                         kernel_size=1,
                         activation=softmax,
                         padding='same',
                         kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=0.01),
                         bias_initializer=Constant(value=0))(multi_array)
```

Considering that my array is 2-dimensional, it has shape just like this - `(N, 96)` (or in Keras, symbolic `(?, 96)`). Problem is, `Conv1D` only accepts a single 1-dimensional vector (as far as I know), but we should pass `N` vectors.

What we could perhaps do, is pass `1D` vectors with iteration (perhaps something like `tf.scan`?). But I do not know how exactly this could be done with abstract layer definitions in Keras.

---

What's the simplest way to pass `2D` such array to `Conv1D`? So that it takes each 96-dimensional row and writes all predictions?

Is this possible at all in Keras? or do I have to create my own layer that does all the iterations?

Comment: If you have a *row vector* as your input it has 1 dimension so you will need to use a `Conv1D` for 1 dimensional convolution instead.

Comment: @nuric Well I didn't think much about that, I guess considering the fact that classification must be done independently, `Conv1D` must be use, I'll fix that right now, thank you! But then again, how do we pass multiple row vectors to `Conv1D`?

Answer (score 0):

```
array_new = np.expand_dims(2D_matrix_dense,2)
```

This will give like (87398, 513, 1)

```
input =  Input(shape=(513, 1),name='features')

x = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',kernel_initializer="he_normal")(input)
```